# Can we use scales that belong to the chord that is in the scale you planned your composition to be in?

Tags: chords, composition, chord-theory

Can we use scales that belong to the chord that is in the scale you planned your composition to be in? For example I'm in a G major chord and there is a D major chord too, can I use the D major scale?

Comment: This is music, not math. You can do whatever you want! Why don't you try it out and decide whether you like the way it sounds?

Comment: @Kevin I disagree that music is not math. Music exists in an intersection where Math, Craft, and Art meet. I do agree that one can do what ever one wants. It is indeed art. But within that there are mathematical rules that you can choose to follow or not. It is true that the math is arbitrary and ruled primarily by taste and culture, but it is valid to be interested in the math. Often musicians escape one math by replacing it with another.

Comment: @amalgamate I think that what Kevin is trying to say is that people shouldn't see these type of things as 'absolute rules' - 'do them or get arrested' like many young students do

Comment: @Shevliaskovic I can agree with your statement but I can not agree with Kevin's. This is the land of learning. The way he put it, he is pointing away from knowledge as if knowing is a bad thing.

Comment: @amalgamate (and Shev)- guidelines are probably what the Op's after. Inexperience calls for some parameters, for safety's and security's sake, if nothing else.  ALL rules are there to be broken, otherwise we'd never have any fun! BUT, without guidelines, we're in a floundering ship...

Comment: @Tim exactly true. We have each said that in our own way (minus Kevin).

Comment: @Tim and it's been said often "before you break the rules, you must know the rules".  There is some wisdom in that quote.

Comment: @RockinCowboy - never a truer word was spoken...

Comment: "Before you break the rules, you must know the rules" - but his only pushes the problem one step further back. How do you know if the person who teaches you the rules *really* "knows the rules" themselves, or if they are just taking part in a game of Chinese Whispers that has been going on for the past few hundred years.

Comment: @alephzero But that is exactly what the "rules" are, they bend and change as popular culture accepts bends and breaks. The rules bend and break and change with popular culture.

Comment: @amalgamate most of the rules are passed down from generation to generation of teachers, and often "those who can't do, teach." Apart from Rameau and Schoenberg, it's hard to name any "great composers" of classical music who ever *published* any "rules". (CPE Bach and Hindemith were "good composers", but not "great" IMO). I expect the same is equally true of popular music.

Comment: @alephzero: Rules do not come from publishing, they come from actual music. Publishing music theory is a mire attempt to codify what we hear, write and play. Your proof is no proof at all. The fact that there are good teachers and bad proves nothing.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, since this is *your* composition, you can do whatever you want. Unless you're going for something very specific, like you want to write your song in a certain style, there are no limits. Go nuts.

In your example, I assume you're in the G major key, and you have a D major chord, right? If this is the case, then yes you can freely use the D *mixolydian* scale. That is like the D major scale with a C natural instead of C#. You can use this scale because it's the V of G. It uses the same notes, but starts off at a different note

Answer (score 6):

I stand with Shevliaskovic on this: You can indeed do what ever you want. Taking your question as written, that is the exact correct response.

However, I believe that this is what you really wanted to know:

It is true that G Major key has a D Major chord as the dominant (fifth chord of the key), and that D Major key has G Major chord as the sub-dominant (fourth chord of the key). This means yes for your specific case, without qualification. If you try, you can find scales and chords that do not match so well as this. G Major and D Major share all notes except C which is Sharp in D Major and natural in G Major.

It is important to note that you can find chords in the D major or G major scale that have a C# or a C natural. Take the C Major Chord In G major. The C Major chord would sound harsh against the **Scale** of D Major in most cases, while the D Major **chord** would sound fine played in the context of a C Major chord. This is proof by negation, that the answer to the OP is "no" because it is not true in all cases of chords and scales based on chords.

BTW Shevliaskovic is absolutely correct as well. You could say my answer is a translation of his. If you do not speak Mode, than learn modes. Learning modes is the deep answer to your question. Your question is an answer (not the only one) to the question "Why should I learn modes?"

Answer (score 3):

Adding further to the two existing answers, the notes of MODES will fit slightly better than the notes of each major scale. On chord G, obviously, the G scale notes fit best. Still in the KEY of G, but on a D chord, the notes of D Mixolydian are a (slightly) better fit, and on a C chord, the notes from C Lydian likewise.

So, what's happening is that on each chord, the notes from the particular mode are best fit. And actually, they're the exact same notes from G major! It's just that they're centred round a different 'home'.

You can use the notes from each major scale, and make them all fit, but care is needed. It can really spice up the melody line if you do this, but ears are the best judges. Don't be bound by rules - what rules!- the theory has been formulated based on what usually works well, so it's a great guideline, but not the law.